# "WARNING: terminal is not fully functional" when using "man" as root

Tags: terminal, man

I know that this question has been posted a zillion times, but none of the answers I could find have solved it for me.

I have a root shell given by `sudo bash`. When I try to use `man`, I have this message:

```
WARNING: terminal is not fully functional
-  (press RETURN)
```

and limited control on navigation.

It works when I'm not root. As root, `aptitude` works correctly. I've tried to `export TERM` with: `linux`, `xterm`, `xterm-color`, `xterm-256color`, `ansi`, `screen-256color`, `ncurses`, `vt100`.

The ouput of `stty -a` is exactly the same as root and non-root:

```
speed 38400 baud; rows 30; columns 271; line = 0;
intr = ^C; quit = ^\; erase = ^?; kill = ^U; eof = ^D; eol = <undef>; eol2 = <undef>; swtch = <undef>; start = ^Q; stop = ^S; susp = ^Z; rprnt = ^R; werase = ^W; lnext = ^V; discard = ^O; min = 1; time = 0;
-parenb -parodd -cmspar cs8 -hupcl -cstopb cread -clocal -crtscts
-ignbrk -brkint -ignpar -parmrk -inpck -istrip -inlcr -igncr icrnl ixon -ixoff -iuclc -ixany -imaxbel iutf8
opost -olcuc -ocrnl onlcr -onocr -onlret -ofill -ofdel nl0 cr0 tab0 bs0 vt0 ff0
isig icanon iexten echo echoe echok -echonl -noflsh -xcase -tostop -echoprt echoctl echoke -flusho -extproc
```

I'm stuck.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `none of the answers I could find have solved it for me` – Please link to these answers or cite them in the question body ([edit] the question). I guess you don't want us to give you answers you have already tried. So what are they?

Comment: I've tried to export TERM with: linux, xterm, xterm-color, xterm-256color, ansi, screen-256color, ncurses, vt100. These are the answers I could gather. Users report that sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't. Which leads me to think it's probably related to something else than "TERM", but I couldn't find out what. I just wanted to point out that I did some research before posting my question.

Comment: Same problem here only on CentOS. Every single thing I've found says "set TERM" but TERM *is* set to something valid, and changing it does nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost 3 years later, ChatGPT gave me the solution...

```
# type man
man is aliased to `TERMINFO=~/.terminfo/ LESS=C TERM=mostlike PAGER=less man'
```

at some point "man" was aliased to a bogus line... that explains why the other users were unaffected...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this myself by adding a missing `ncurses` package which provides /usr/share/terminfo. This package, which for whatever reason of package dependency hell, wasn't installed, seems to fix this. Though in my case it happened to both `root` and non-root users alike, so it might not be it, but worth posting I think in case anyone is in my situation in the future and comes across this question in Google results.

On CentOS, it's `ncurses-base`.

On Debian 11 (and likely Ubuntu's), it's `ncurses-term`.

If you're missing those packages, try installing them and seeing if that helps.

I found this by trying to do `reset` on the terminal, and the resulting "Terminal type?" prompt rejecting everything I tried, e.g.

```
Terminal type? screen                                      
reset: unknown terminal type screen
Terminal type?                                             
Terminal type? vt100
reset: unknown terminal type vt100
```

That got me comparing it against a working system, and looking for anything that included the name `vt100`. A bit of digging through the `grep -r` results led me to the files under `/usr/share/terminfo` which were missing on the "bad" system. A call to `rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/share/terminfo/v/vt100` led me to that package name.